# How to place plot legends in two rows?

Tags: plotting, legending

For example

```
ListPlot[Array[# &, {4, 4}], 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, {Left, Bottom}]]
```

How to place the plot legends as {{a,b},{c,d}}?

Comment: What do you mean “as {{a, b}, {c, d}}”? Can you explain where and what you would like placed?

Comment: @MarcoB i want to place them as a matrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an explicit `PointLegend` with `LegendLayout` set to do this:

```
ListPlot[Array[# &, {4, 4}], 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[
        PointLegend[{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}], 
        {Left, Bottom}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have found the option 'LegendLayout' in the document, but this usage is not mentioned in the document

Comment: @Brett Please document this. This is very useful: I have been looking for it in the past too, and could not find it.